# LESS - go back to grandparent if child exists

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, less, chaining, nested

This one is making me crazy.

I have labels component in bootstrap v3.
Labels have modifiers like label-danger (red color), label-success(green) etc.
There is a need to distinguish whether label is a link or not.

I have a two lists, one have anchors as child element, other does not:

```
<ul id="labels1">
    <li>Success</li>
    <li>Danger</li>
```

```
<ul id="labels2">
    <li><a href="#">Success</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Danger</a></li>
</ul>
```

Next thing is the labels.less which looks like this:

```
.label {
  display: inline;
  padding: .25em .6em;
  font-size: 75%;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 1;
  vertical-align: middle;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: @grayLight;
  border-radius: .25em;

  a,
  a:hover,
  a:focus,
  a&,
  a&:hover,
  a&:focus {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
}

.label-danger {
  background-color: @label-danger-bg;
  a& {
    background-color: darken(@label-danger-bg, 10%);
  }
}
.label-success {
  background-color: @label-success-bg;
  a& {
    background-color: darken(@label-success-bg, 10%);
  }
}
```

Next thing is - I have a LESS mastersheet where I define:

```
#labels1 {
    li {
        .label;
        &:first-child {
            .label-success;
        }
        &:last-child {
            .label-danger;
        }
    }
}
```

And it's OK untill this part:

```
#labels2 {
    li {
        a {
            .label;
        }
        &:first-child {
            a {
                .label-success;
            }
        }
        &:last-child {
            a {
                .label-danger;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

There is no way to tell through LESS that I am styling a `a` element so it should have a darker color.

If I do something like this:

```
#labels2 {
    li {
        &:first-child {
            .label;
            .label-success;
        }
        //  etc
    }
}
```

It will just produce normal colors (not those darker).

What I would like to do is to find a workaround for something that does not exist in LESS (grandparent selector matching in chain):

```
.label-success {
  background-color: @label-success-bg;
  a {
    && { // go 2 levels up and style the .label-success 
         // if LESS can dig to this rule - eg. if there technically 
         // exists an anchor inside the li.
        background-color: darken(@label-success-bg, 10%);
    }
  }
}
```

Does anyone have idea what to do is such case?

Comment: Are you asking for `a&` like in `labels.less`?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you need the "&" in your rule.  It should be:

```
.label-danger {
  background-color: @label-danger-bg;
  a {
    background-color: darken(@label-danger-bg, 10%);
  }
}
.label-success {
  background-color: @label-success-bg;
  a {
    background-color: darken(@label-success-bg, 10%);
  }
}
```

Then your rules for #labels1 should work for both:

```
#labels1, #labels2 {
    li {
        .label;
        &:first-child {
            .label-success;
        }
        &:last-child {
            .label-danger;
        }
    }
}
```